# Ubuntu 18.04 MT7921 Drivers not available

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, kernel

I bought an ASUS Vivobook Pro, which I believe comes with a Mediatek MT7921 Network adapter.

Currently, after install Ubuntu 18.04, it is unable to find a wifi adapter and the screen brightness controls do not work.

I have tried solutions from other users recommending to upgrade the linux kernel. However when I try to upgrade it to anything too high (e.g. 5.17) I get a libssl dependency issue and the headers are not installed. If I try to download something slightly older but supposedly has the fixes for my drivers (e.g. 5.12.5), I get a libc6 dependency error and the headers are not installed. If I try ignoring it and reboot, the system gets stuck at boot screen and not render the GUI.

Is there a way for me to install the drivers necessary to get Wi-Fi and brightness controls back. Or worst case just the brightness controls.

Also, I cannot upgrade to anything higher than ubuntu 18.04, as the tools I use at university require Ubuntu 18.

Please let me know if there is any additional information that is needed to fix this issue.

```
$ uname -r
5.4.0-131-generic
$ lspci -nnk  grep 0280 -A3
lspci: No such PCI access method: 3 (see `-A help' for a list)
$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1630
00:00.2 IOMMU: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1631
00:01.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1632
00:02.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1632
00:02.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1634
00:02.4 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1634
00:08.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1632
00:08.1 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1635
00:08.2 PCI bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1635
00:14.0 SMBus: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SMBus Controller (rev 51)
00:14.3 ISA bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH LPC Bridge (rev 51)
00:18.0 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166a
00:18.1 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166b
00:18.2 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166c
00:18.3 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166d
00:18.4 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166e
00:18.5 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 166f
00:18.6 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1670
00:18.7 Host bridge: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1671
01:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. Device 7961
02:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller: Sandisk Corp Device 5009 (rev 01)
03:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1638 (rev c5)
03:00.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Device 1637
03:00.2 Encryption controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15df
03:00.3 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1639
03:00.4 USB controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 1639
03:00.5 Multimedia controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e2 (rev 01)
03:00.6 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Device 15e3
04:00.0 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
04:00.1 SATA controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] FCH SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 81)
```

Comment: Please try a live session of 20.04 or 22.10 after making sure Secure Boot is disabled in UEFI. There really no point in troubleshooting a release that will be out of support in a few months. Besides your hardware is likely much newer than 18.04.

Comment: @ChanganAuto The issue is that I have to use Ubuntu 18.04 for the software I use to work.

Comment: So ask the work people what they plan to do when 18.04 is EOL next April.

Comment: This ^^^ Are they planning for a software update? If not, they should.

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk  grep 0280 -A3` and also: `uname -r` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @chili555 I have updated the question.

Comment: Oops! Sorry :-(( I meant to say: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Please forgive my mis-step and try again.

Comment: Would it be ok to run Ubuntu 22.04 and use 18.05 in a virtual machine